# What does this regex mean? <!--.*?-->

Tags: regular-expression

What does this regex do?

```
<!--.*?-->
```

Comment: Why downvote question and then upvote answers? It looks like legit beginner question. It could benefit from some details (e.g. which regex flavour: vim, perl, extended .. or example usage).

Answer (score 6):

This regular expression will match [HTML comments](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_comment.asp)

In particular:

```
<!-- matches literal string "<!--"
.    matches any character
*    is a quantifier, it means "0 or more" of the previous character
?    makes the regex non-greedy, so it matches as few times as possible
--> matches literal "-->"
```

So, your regexp against this text:

```
blah <!-- first --> yaddahyaddah <!-- second --> other random words.
```

will match only `<!-- first -->`.

See http://regex101.com/r/gF7vX2/1

Without the ? it would match everything between the first occurrence of `<!--` and the final `-->`, in other words it would match: `<!-- first --> yaddahyaddah <!-- second -->`

See http://regex101.com/r/fP4kA3/1

Answer (score 3):

- `<!--` matches the characters `<!--` literally
- `.` matches any character (except newline)
- `*?` is a quantifier that matches the preceding regex between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
- `-->` matches the characters `-->` literally

Answer from the regex tester http://regex101.com/r/lA1bH5/2

Note that `*` matches the preceding regex between zero and unlimited times,
as *many* times as possible. 
This is an important distinction. 
Consider the following two regexs:

- A: `<!--.*?-->`   (the one you asked about)
- B: `<!--.*-->`

And consider data line D, which is shown below. 
Regex A will find two matches in it; regex B finds only one:

```
D: <!-- comment one --> HTML <!-- comment two -->

A: (.... match #1 ....)      (.... match #2 ....)
B: (................. match #1 .................)
```

So regex B will incorrectly treat the HTML between the two comments
as if it were in a comment.

Comment: The explanation by rob is correct. You could use such regular expressions to modify comments in HTML or XML files.